# why the result of the iterator obtain from its end() is strange?

Tags: c++

I get a problem when I was doing some practice of "c++ prime", there is something wrong with iterator end(). So I write a test file, and its code is below:

```
int main (void) 
{ 
    vector<int> v(10); 
    auto c = v.end(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

What makes me surprise is the value of c is not 10, but a strange number. Here is my debug result:

[image]

What's the reason of this problem? Is it due to the compiler? I use "g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14" to compile.

Comment: Why would the value of `c` be 10? It's an iterator, not a number, and it's even a "past the end" iterator that is invalid to dereference.

Comment: For std::vector<>, an iterator is not an index, it is a pointer. A pointer is a number that refers to a location in memory. If you want to convert it to an index, you will need to substract v.begin() from it: v.end() - v.begin(), then you will get 10 as you expected.

Comment: Can we just consider iterator as pointer or is there something different between them? I am just a beginner in c++ and used c ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `iterator::end` points to a location one past the last element in the container. So the address that it points to, in your case, is the one which is **after** the address that stores the 10th element of your `vector`.

Moreover, looks like you are trying to access the value of the iterator, which is the address in the memory it is pointing to. You need to `dereference` it in order to get the **value** it points to (not applicable for `iterator::end`).

Comment: The address does not store 10 (I think that you know what you say, but the way you say it will make it even more confusing for the guy who asked the question), please edit !

Comment: No, it's not the point, what I mean in your sentence is "that stores 10", the address does not *store* 10.

Comment: @HappyCoder - 10 isn't a value, but the size of the vector.

Comment: Ah. Missed it! I think I should call it a day!

Comment: @HappyCoder: amen to that.

Comment: I got it , what the gdb shows is not the iterator's value, but the value that the iterator points to. Such as " *c  = 135121" instead of "c = 135121", right?

Comment: Nope. You're trying to dereference `iterator::end`, which is UB!

Answer (score 3):

The *type* of `v.end()` is a `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Essentially a vector iterator is a pointer to an element of that vector.

`v.end()` points to memory one element past the end of the vector. C++ allows you to store that value (due to the one-past-the-array-rule) and compare it with other pointers in your vector. That's why you can use it as a stopping point in your `for` loop.

What you see in your output is essentially a `cout`-style stringification which is the pointer address.

C++ does **not** allow you to *deference* `v.end()`. That would be undefined behaviour.